# Clisp + Emacs compile-and-load-file

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

Starting to learn Common lisp. Instal in my debian 5.03 clisp, emacs-23.1 and slime.

Write in .emacs:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/clisp") ; your Lisp system
     (add-to-list 'load-path "/home/slime/")  ; your SLIME directory
     (require 'slime)
     (slime-setup '(slime-scratch slime-editing-commands slime-repl))

(global-font-lock-mode t) 
(show-paren-mode 1) 
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook '(lambda () 
      (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))
```

Then create in emacs new lisp file: test.lisp write simple lisp expression:

```
(defun square(x)
  (* x x))
```

Then try to compile this code `C-c C-k` and see in minibuffer: *Not connected*

p.s. Now i try to click in eval defun in emacs main menu: and see in minibuffer: *Process lisp does not exist*

What's wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens if you do M-x slime ? 
I looks like you don't have slime started.

Comment: I write M-x slime in minibuffer and after that create new buffer REPL with CL-USER>

Comment: OK, now what happens if you go back to test.lisp and press C-c C-k?

Comment: After C-c C-k creates 2 files: test.fas and test.lib

Comment: And after that in minibuffer: Lisp connection closed unexpectedly: connection broken by remote server

Comment: You're on your way then.  You should be able to use square in the slime repl. Good luck.